# use generateStaticParams() in layout.tsx NextJS 14 app directory to get dynamic rotes prerendered (PPR)

Tags: reactjs, next.js14, pre-rendering

The idea is to make `/[locale]/en` and `/[locale]/ka` directories generated statically with [PPR](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/partial-prerendering). Interesting is that without the `locale`, as a parameter, the `/` directory has PPR sign after it is build (`npm run build`), but whenever I set the [dynamic rote](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#dynamic-paths-getstaticpaths) as `/[locale]/layout.tsx` and have the main page under `app/[locale]/(home)/page.tsx` all rotes (`/ka` and `/en`) become dynamic.

Here is the output after build is completed (λ server-rendered on demand):

```
├ λ /[locale]                              12.8 kB         113 kB    
├   ├ /en
├   └ /ka
```

when we have the directory that looks like:

```
├ /[locale]  
    ├ /layout.tsx                            
    └ /(home)
        └ /page.tsx
```

expected build (Partial Prerender ◐):

```
├ ◐ /[locale]                              12.8 kB         113 kB    
├   ├ /en
├   └ /ka
```

So far, what I have noticed, is that `generateStaticParams()` function is only in `/page/tsx` files in examples provided by NextJS. The current content looks like below:

```js
//src\app\[locale]\layout.tsx

import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import './globals.css';

export const dynamic = 'force-static';

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  params: { locale: string };
}) {
  return (
    <html lang={params.locale}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const locales = ['en', 'ka'];
  return locales.map((locale) => ({ locale }));
}
```

```js
//src\app\[locale]\(home)\page.tsx

import { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Skeleton } from '../components/layout/skeletons';
import ServerComponent from './components/banners/';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between ">
      <Suspense fallback={<Skeleton/>}>
        <ServerComponent/>
      </Suspense>
      
    </main>
  );
}
```